# Android Studio emulator only visible in the task bar

Tags: flutter, android-studio, emulation

I'm flutter beginner. I run the emulator. but it looks for a moment when you start, and then disappeared. After that, it only appears on the taskbar and cannot be seen by clicking.
I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Right click</kbd>, but there was no response. The same problem occurred in vscode. Please help..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not android studio, try reinstalling sdk platform-tools and checking if you have any pending update

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall old emulator and install new emulator and update SDK as well